# Xcode: Unable to create IPA file (option is missing)

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipa, codesign

As you know the option to create an IPA file normally appears after pressing Distribute in Organizer. It is supposed to say "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc deployment". In my case it does not say this. I can only save an xarchive or make a backup.

My setup: Xcode 5. I have an iOS Objective C project that has 4 sub-projects, each of which is compiled for static linking (dynamic causes errors). Everything builds and links properly. I can run the app on an i-device with no provisioning profile just fine.

When I create a provisioning profile, download it and tell Xcode to use it, the code sign however fails very frequently. Xcode removes these profiles from the list during the "Fix It" phase.

In addition, we are seeing something truly bizarre in that our newly created provisioning profiles will be valid for only a matter of minutes and then will switch to invalid, and if we disable Data Protection in our App Id settings, about 10 minutes later it will mysteriously become re-enabled.

Any ideas about what might be going wrong?

Comment: Might be issue in creation of certificate,, so recreate it again and also update your provisioning profile. and install it all again.

Comment: Do you have a copy of Apple's certificate in your keychain? I forget the name, but it's available for download in the portal at about the same spot where you download your own certificate.

Comment: @Caleb I definitely have their certificate. One thing that is probably confusing OS/X is that I switched from one development account (company A) to another (company B). So I am doing a reinstall of the OS tonight.

Comment: @iPatel I did try that. Every time I created a new profile for the new certificate, it became invalid within minutes. One detail though : that the certificate that I continued to use had been auto generated by Xcode.